# For Loop to Build DataFrame with List of Given Variables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, elementtree

I have a `For loop` that iterates and finds pre-defined list of variables as shown in `List_Object` from multiple XML files using `ElementTree` lib in python, `append` the text value into a new list from XML, store individual lists into corresponding DataFrame `df1, df2, etc` with Pandas, and finally export the data to an Excel spreadsheet.

All the codes worked fine. However, when I tried not to hard code the variable by replacing it with `List_Object[num]` in `tree.findall()`, the output becomes strange. I think the logics for the loop was mistaken, causing it escape the `for loop` and change `num` every time appending new data. Also, the code `dic["df{}".format(int)]` to store appended data into corresponding dataframe does not seem working. I wonder if there is another way to do this or what kind of constrains should I add to this for loop.

Here is `for loop` and global variables:

```
data_folder = Path("C:/xxx")

Data=[]
List_Object = ['verID','User_name']  #set two variables
n_list = len(List_Object) # number of variables
dic = {}

...
...
for file in data_folder.rglob('*.xml'): # get file path for each XML file
  file_path = data_folder / file

  with open(file_path, "rb"): # open file_path and parse as tree
    tree = ET.parse(file_path)

    for num in range(n_list):  # determine the numbers of dataframes are made
      for value in tree.findall(List_Object[num]):  # search for values from XML with the string variable provided from List_Object
          Data.append(value.text)  # append values from XML
          dic["df{}".format(int)] = pd.DataFrame(Data) # store appended data into corresponding dataframe (df1, df2, df3, etc.)

...

df_merge = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1) # To merge dataframe. At this point, I only add two
df_merge.to_excel('output.xlsx') # output to xlsx
```

Here is expected Excel output:

```
         Ver  Column_2
0      1.0.1  Apple
1      1.0.2  B
2      1.0.3  Cat
3      1.0.4  D
4      1.0.5  E
5      1.0.6  F
6      1.0.7  Gorilla
..     ..     ..
```

But the actual output is:

```
         Ver  Column_2
0      1.0.1   1.0.1
1      Apple   Apple
2      1.0.2   1.0.2
3        B      B
4      1.0.3   1.0.3
5       cat     cat
6      1.0.4   1.0.4
..      ..     ..
```

`print num` from the `tree.findall` loop shows as follows, so is from `List_Object[num]`

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
...
```

```
ver
column_2
ver
column_2
ver
...
```

`tree` are `parsed` file paths (all XML files in the data_folder):

```
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x0(address)>
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x0(address)>
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x0(address)>
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x0(address)>
...
```

the sample XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sections>
  ...
  <User_name>Apple</User_name>
  <verID>1.0.1</verID>
  ...
</sections>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a representative sample of what `tree` looks like?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting updated the completed code, and added both `print(tree)` and sample XML file

Comment: You left out the most important parts: in your sample xml file, there are no cats, gorillas, etc.  Please edit the question again, and make sure that the sample xml contains all the elements which are supposed to show up in your expected output.

Comment: @Jack Fleeting it is supposed to extract the same infor on `User_name` and `verID` for multiple XML files in the folder. So, the second XML has the same structure with `User_name` as B and `verID` as 1.02, the third XML has `User_name` as Cat and `verID` as 1.02, and so on